# Bitwise comparision of two directories(files) in Perl

Tags: perl, bit-manipulation

I am trying to achieve the follwing using perl

A script that performs bitwise comparison of files from two directories
(the directory names are passed as arguments to the script in the command line).
The script should read all files from the first directory and all subdirectories, and
compare them to the corresponding files (e.g. files with the same names) in the
second directory.

The result of the script - (PASSED or FAILED) is formed according to:
The result is FAILED when at least one file from the first directory is not bitwise
equal to the corresponding file in the second directory or the second directory
has no corresponding file.
Otherwise test is PASSED.

So far I have tried the approach in this thread created by me - [Comparing two directories using Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477905/comparing-two-directories-using-perl/9480331#9480331) . After some point I realized I am essentially trying to do simulate "diff -r dir1 dir2" which isn't the goal, How can one perform bitwise comparision operation on two directories?

```
EDIT: Test Case

  /dir1                       /dir2
       -- file1                   -- file1 
       -- file2                   -- file2  
       -- file3 
       -- ....
       -- ...
       ---/subDir1
            --file1
            --file2

file1 of dir1 contains :- foo bar
file1  of dir2 contains :- foo 
Result - Fail

file1  of dir1 contains :- foo bar
file1  of dir2 contains :- foo bar
Result - Pass.
```

The script should essentially extract files with same names present in different directories.

Comment: When you say "bitwise", do you mean they have the same content, the same metadata, the same content and metadata, or something else?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2847914/how-can-i-use-perl-to-determine-whether-the-contents-of-two-files-are-identical

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

1. Open dir1
2. Read all filenames into an array
3. Open dir2
4. Read all filenames into an array
5. For any case in which a filename in dir1 matches a filename in dir2 or vice versa, begin compare logic
6. Use Digest::MD5 [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/Digest/MD5.html) to perform an MD5 comparison of the two files.  If even one bit is off, you will get different checksums.

Code example from Digest::MD5...

```
 use Digest::MD5 qw(md5 md5_hex md5_base64);
 $digest = md5($data);
 $digest = md5_hex($data);
 $digest = md5_base64($data);
 # OO style
 use Digest::MD5;
 $ctx = Digest::MD5->new;
 $ctx->add($data);
 $ctx->addfile(*FILE);
 $digest = $ctx->digest;
 $digest = $ctx->hexdigest;
 $digest = $ctx->b64digest;
```

Generate an MD5 hash for each file and compare them, then pass or fail accordingly.

Comment: This can be pretty expensive for big directories. I'd check with something like stat to see if they can even have matching digests. If they aren't the same size, for instance, you already know they aren't the same.

Comment: Why calculate a hash that's only used once? It's cheaper and more accurate to compare every byte then to compute their MD5 hash, especially since you can stop as soon as a difference is encountered when comparing bytes. A hash is useful when comparing one file with many, many files to many files, and when the files to compare are not on the same system.

Comment: True, it depends a lot on how many files you have and how large they are.  If we're talking about a few hundred small files, you can churn out hashes and comparisons in just a few seconds.  Terabytes of data?  Not so easy. I just suggested this as a very simple method to compare two files to see if they are identical, using well-known and well-documented MD5 tools.  YMMV. :)