# Perl DirCompare exclude dirs

Tags: perl, directory

I got a code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9480331/7210702) to compare the differences in all the files present in the directories recursively

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::DirCompare;
use File::Basename;

sub compare_dirs
{
  my ($dir1, $dir2) = @_;
  my $equal = 1;

  File::DirCompare->compare($dir1, $dir2, sub {
    my ($a,$b) = @_;
    $equal = 0; # if the callback was called even once, the dirs are not equal

    if ( !$b )
    {
      printf "File '%s' only exists in dir '%s'.\n", basename($a), dirname($a);
    }
    elsif ( !$a ) {
      printf "File '%s' only exists in dir '%s'.\n", basename($b), dirname($b);
    }
    else
    {
      printf "File contents for $a and $b are different.\n";
    }
  });

  return $equal;
}

print "Please specify two directory names\n" and exit if (@ARGV < 2);
printf "%s\n", &compare_dirs($ARGV[0], $ARGV[1]) ? 'Test: PASSED' : 'Test: FAILED';
```

I want to exclude some of the directories like .old, .pro, etc.

I dont find a way to do this here?

Answer (score 0):

**solution 1**

According to the [DirCompare documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~gavinc/File-DirCompare-0.3/DirCompare.pm), you can provide a fourth argument to the compare function (cmp) and do a custom test.

**solution 2**

Another way is to test $dir1 and $dir2 for excluded directory names, and to set $equal to 0 only if $dir1 and $dir2 are not excluded.

```
if ( not_excluded($dir1) && not_excluded($dir2) ) {
 $equal = 0;
}
```

(not_excluded being a custom function written by you, returning true if provided dir is not excluded)